# Regarding recursive file run and replace the main content of input file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

```
sed "s/eth0/$change/" <  ifcfg-eth0
```

Our file contains:

```
DEVICE=eth0
```

I want to replace the `eth0` with any input I enter, every time I run the program.
To be specific, the above mentioned command does the following:

Every time I run my program, it asks to enter the value which we want in order to replace `eth0`. It does replace it once but the next time I run the script, it does not work because it no longer has `eth0` as a pattern in the file which it can change.

`sed -i` will only make the changes once but i need it recursively..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed -i "s/^DEVICE=\(.*\)/DEVICE=$change/" ifcfg-eth0`. This should replace the any pattern after `DEVICE=` with `$change`.

Comment: one more doubt can we use -r and -i together. because i have  afie which has many parameters that has to be changed

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean "recursively" you mean more than once. And your problem is that you are matching the wrong thing.

Don't match the value you want to change match the *line* you want to change.

Match `/^DEVICE=/` that is and replace the part of the line you care about or the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

**file.txt:**

```
DEVICE=eth0
```

Try this:

```
$ change=wlan0
$ sed -r "s/(.*=).*/\1$change/" file.txt
DEVICE=wlan0
$ change=eth0
$ sed -r "s/(.*=).*/\1$change/" file.txt
DEVICE=eth0
```

Comment: But if i need to replace the content of change in my actual input file. then how am i suppose to do that?